# Alternative http pubsub platform to SNS

Tags: http-post, publish-subscribe, amazon-sns

I tried to use SNS as platform to post http messages to clients, but it have 2 major problems.

1. i can't send the subscribers id's / endpoints dynamically. i must create a topic for every combination, but the combinations change every time according to specific message parameters which change very often.
2. trying to make a work around the 1 issue, i tried to create a service which will generate the topics run-time, but even when i create new topic i need confirmation from the client after adding him to the subscribers considering this happens pretty often i can't expect clients to confirm being added endlessly which creates an issue even so.

can anyone suggest alternative service which uses http to publish the messages?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an SNS subscription model and just create endpoints in the SNS application as the users register/login your app.
You will have to store on the back end a mapping of the users account to the endpoint ARN.

FYI, any one user can have many endpoints and some may be invalid.